# Why will my button work, but not my key bind?

Tags: python

In this section of the code, I try to set the button's command to `goRun`, and also bind the `Return` key to `goRun`.

```
def goRun():
    Run.runData(ENTRY=symbolEntry.get(), GREATER=greaterEntry.get(), BETWEEN=betweenEntry.get(), LESSER=lesserEntry.get())
    #^ "Run" is a seperate class.

button = Button(app, text="Go Data", command=goRun, fg="blue")
button.pack(side="top", pady=2, padx=10)

app.bind('<Return>', goRun)
```

When I run the app, and press the `Return` key, I get this error:

```
TypeError: goRun() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

But when I press the button, it runs the command and works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What GUI library are you using?

Comment: This is almost certainly `tkinter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the GUI library you are using is `tkinter`, this is because when a callback is activated by a keypress, a parameter called `event` is passed. Try modifying your function definition so it is like this:

```
def goRun(event=None):
```

So you are getting the error as your function received a parameter with which it doesn't have a clue what to do. With the `event=None` we are saying "Don't worry about that argument when it comes along, it's nothing."

You get this error with the `Return` key because it gives this argument, but it works with your `Button` as it does not send the argument.

Comment: actually, `event=None` does _not_ mean "Don't worry about that argument when it comes along". Rather, it means "I expect an argument here, but if I don't get one, set it to None". It's a convenient way to use a function both as a callback from an event, and from other places in your code where you don't have an event object to pass in such as using with as the object of a `command` attribute which does not send an event.